# Search and replace with regex in dreamweaver

Tags: php, regex, dreamweaver

Can anybody help me with following

I have several variables like

```
$customer = $this->input->post('UserId_2');
```

and I need to replace with

```
$customer = $this->input->post('UserId_2', TRUE);
```

I am using the following RegEx to search which matches all the occurrences

```
\$this->input->post\(\'\w*\'\);
```

But I am unable to replace. I have tried $1 but it doesn't help

Comment: Do you just want to add ", TRUE" in the end before );?

Comment: The PHP tag should be removed. This is just a regex/ DW question.

Comment: Couldn't you introduce a default value for the second parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a capture group so `$1` is empty. Use:

```
\$this->input->post\('(\w*)'\);
```

with

```
$this->input->post('$1', TRUE);
```

[image: DW Screenshot]

Comment: You should remove `customer = ` from replace part https://regex101.com/r/A6tcaD/1/